# Spark - why application slower with more executors?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 executors and they are using 4 cores each with 3gb memory i've got an answer in 1.9 min but when I'm giving num of executors 8 with one core each it gives me answer in 12 mins, why the result is so different?

Comment: Can you say a bit more of what you are doing specifically? It could be that your data is good enough with 2 executors and adding executors is just spreading data more.

Comment: I was using mysql database and in that I have 5.7 GB data and I was reading the data via spark. When I was running a query on it via spark it gave me the result in 1.9 minutes(2 executors, 4 cores/executor, executor memory 3gb, partitions 8) but when I increase the number of executors(8 executors, 1 core/executor, 1gb of executor memory, 8 partitions) so I got the query result in 12 minutes.
I was wondering why it is so different as it is the same thing I guess.